# Django setting models.DateField() with a datetime object

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, python-datetime

I'm debugging some failing test after we recently upgraded from django 1.11 to 2.2, and i've noticed a behaviour that i havent been aware before.

consider the following code

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta

class User(models.Model):
    birthday = DateField()

user = User.objects.create(birthday=date.today())

# setting the DateField object with datetime
yesterday_datetime = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
user.birthday = yesterday_datetime
user.save()

user.refresh_from_db()
print(user.birthday)     # returns date.today()
```

I've always assumed that when a DateField object has been populated with a datetime object, that the date aspect of the datetime object is taken and saved. It seems like this is not the case, and the field isnt updated / saved to the db.

Is this a django 2+ behaviour or has this been the default for quite some time? Can anyone share their experience with this edge case?

Comment: You can use a built-in property of Django called `auto_now_add=True`, just add the argument in field, and the field will be updated the first time you add an entry... if you want to update the field for each update, use `auto_now=True` instead. e.g `date_created = DateField(auto_now=True)`

Comment: i'm familiar with auto_now and auto_now_add, the created_by is just an example above. my main concern is that DateFields populated with datetime objects are not saved and no error is shown to user. i'll edit and change the date variable as not to confuse w/ auto_now

Comment: It's weird, did you try to update it with a totally different value for instance, 7 days before.

Comment: This is most likely  timezone related, Django probably converts your naive `datetime` object to some timezone aware datetime, before converting it to `.date` and you get a different date as side effect. Try to use `timezone.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`. PS. you didn't mention if have switched to `USE_TZ = True` during the upgrade.

Comment: @Todor can confirm that this is timezone related, i played around and changed the days difference to be 7days, 30days as suggestion by Lemayzeur, and the date aspect of the datetime is actually saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue is related to timezone. You can set DateField with a datetime object and it saves the date aspect of that. But timezone has to be considered.